# How to handle Kubernetes workload certificates?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I want to deploy a MongoDB cluster with for example [Percona](https://www.percona.com/doc/kubernetes-operator-for-psmongodb/index.html). So, I need to provide a certificate to MongoDB servers and MongoDB client applications to use TLS. In this use case, the certificate must be signed for `*.mongodb-namespace.svc.cluster.local`. If I generate this certificate, it will be self-signed, so all client applications will need to set `insecureTLS=true` or `skipVerifyName=true`. This is insecure, so how do we handle certificates in Kubernetes for workloads (generally, here, MongoDB was just an example)?

Comment: please check [Configuring MySQL SSL/TLS authentication with cert-manager](https://www.jetstack.io/blog/securing-mysql-with-cert-manager/). Is that the idea you are looking for?

Comment: Here, the CA is self-signed. So, do client applications need to enable a skipTlsVerify or TLSinsecure options?